# how can i overcome css font cont-family tag,

Tags: css

i am converting psd to html and font used in psd is moolboran, my tag  `font-family: MoolBoran;`, which is not supported by browsers, how can i overcome this problem? is there any possible solution to as alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Your options are to either save an image with your non-standard font, or use the CSS property `font-face`, and allow the site visitors to download the font file. For more details of this approach, see [CSS 3: Custom Fonts Using @font-face](http://return-true.com/2010/05/css-3-custom-fonts-using-font-face/).

Comment: using cufon to creater images, i think its teh best way.

Answer (score 1):

Web safe fonts have been a bane to designers for a while, but you can check out [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) to see if there's a font that's close (it doesn't look like they support MoolBoran unfortunately)

Comment: using cufon to creater images, i think its teh best way.

Answer (score 0):

The only solutions are to

A) use an image rather than live text (which is generally a poor method)

B) See if a web font version of "MoolBoran" is available somewhere. And use the @font-family selector. I looked but can't find anything for it.

C) Change your design.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that tag, it's certainly supported by all browsers.

The font does of course have to be installed on the visitors computer, which is probably where you have your problem.

If you want that exact font, you can make an image out of the text. That is the only sure way to get exactly the look that you want across all browsers.

You should supply fallback fonts in your tag, for example:

```
font-family: MoolBoran, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
```